# Why is the Java compiler losing track of generic types in constructor instantiation?

Tags: java, generics, types, constructor, type-inference

Given a generic class `Test<T>` and a constructor that takes the `Class` of the generic parameter `public Test(Class<T> clazz){}`
Why doesn't the compiler correctly infer that generic type on constructor instantiation `new Test(String.class)`

When calling the constructor `new Test(String.class)` the compiler seems to not infer the type `Test<String>`

What's the reason for this? Using a static factory method, the compiler infers the correct type:

**Test.java**

```java
class Test<T> {
    public Test(Class<T> clazz) {}

    public static <C> Test<C> create(Class<C> clazz) {
        return new Test<>(clazz);
    }
}
```

```java
Test<Integer> y = new Test(String.class); // works fine at both compile time and runtime, runtime error occurs when calling another method that relies on the generic type parameter

//Test<Integer> x = Test.create(String.class); // does not compile
```

Comment: By not using `<>` parameters (as would have been `new Test<>(String.class);`), the generic typing is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joop Eggen mentioned in his comment, the Problem was using a raw type by omitting the diamond operator `<>` when instantiating the Test class

```java
//Test<Integer> y = new Test<>(String.class); // doesn't compile
//Test<Integer> y = new Test<String>(String.class); // doesn't compile

Test<String> y = new Test<>(String.class); // compiles with correct types
```

[Raw Types Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)